# How do I get alphabet from the user

Tags: c++, encryption, vigenere

I have a trouble with this. I writing a code for the "vigenere cipher".

I have text and key. But i want to get alphabet from the user. what the user wants etc:"abcdfgh" or "sdgfjdgkfdsgs" just what the user wants.

So but i can't do it.

How do I get alphabet from the user?

Firstly, i want to do get alphabet from the user.
After, I want it to enter the word and encrypt it. But the words alphabet is user's alphabet.

```
Here is the codes:
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 // Bu fonksiyon bir key oluşturur.
  string generateKey(string str, string key) 
 {
 int x = str.size();

 for (int i = 0; ; i++)
  {
      if (x == i)
        i = 0;
      if (key.size() == str.size()) // eğer oluşturulan key boyutu girilen 
    metnin boyutuna eşitse fonksiyonu durdur.
        break;
    key.push_back(key[i]);
}
return key;
    }
    string cipherText(string str, string key) // "/Bu fonksiyon orjinal metni şifreler \"
      {
    string cipher_text;

   for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
  {
    // converting in range 0-25 
    int x = (str[i] + key[i]) % 26;

    // alfabeyi ASCII kodlarina dönüştür:
    x += 'A';

    cipher_text.push_back(x);
 }
       return cipher_text;
  }

    //  "/Bu fonksiyon şifreli metni orjinal hale getirir\"

      string originalText(string cipher_text, string key)
    {
string orig_text;

for (int i = 0; i < cipher_text.size(); i++)
{
    // converting in range 0-25 
    int x = (cipher_text[i] - key[i] + 26) % 26;

    // convert into alphabets(ASCII) 
    x += 'A';
    orig_text.push_back(x);
}
return orig_text;
       }
        int main()
          {
cout << " Sifrelenmesini istediginiz kelimeyi/cumleyi giriniz" << endl;
string str;
getline(cin, str);

//string str = "METINBUGRA";
cout << "Anahtar kelimeyi giriniz." << endl;
string keyword;
getline(cin, keyword);
//string keyword = "ABC";

string key = generateKey(str, keyword);
string cipher_text = cipherText(str, key);

cout << "Sifrelenmis Kelime : "
    << cipher_text << "\n";

cout << "Cozumlenmis kelime : "
    << originalText(cipher_text, key);
system("pause");
return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question, you want to use a custom alphabet instead of English alphabet. For instance you may add digits.

1. Instead of actual letters you must **operate on numbers**: `0, 1, 2, ... N-1`, where `N` is the size of the alphabet. For English alphabet this means you must use `0` instead of `A` (`0x41`), `1` instead of `B` (`0x42`), ... `25` instead of `Z`.
2. If the size of the key is `M`, the encryption algorithm for letter at position `i` is:

   **`( L[i] + K[i mod M] ) mod N`**

   Once you have a functional algorithm that operates on numbers, all you have to do is **map your input from letters to numbers** and your **output from numbers to letters**.
3. Mapping numbers to letters is easy; you just have to store the alphabet into a string – **this answers your question**:

   ```
   string n_to_letter; // alphabet
   //...
   int main()
   {
     //...
     cin >> n_to_letter; // read the alphabet
     //...
   ```
4. **Mapping letters to numbers** is probably beyond your current knowledge; you must use a **`map`**:

   ```
   #include <map>
   //...
   string n_to_letter; // alphabet
   map< char, int > letter_to_n;

   void init_letter_to_n() //...
   ```

   If you do not know how to use a map, there is a **workaround**: just search for the letter in the alphabet string, or use a 256 characters vector/string.

**[DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/WEexNs)**